# Offset between text and cursor with the Monaco editor (Angular) under Chrome / MacOS

Tags: angular, monaco-editor

Using the editor in an Angular application, we can see an offset between text and cursor. For example, if we want to erase a character at the position of the cursor, the character at two or three position before is deleted.

This only occurs using Chrome under MacOS. We don't have this behavior for Firefox / Safari on MacOS and Chrome / Firefox on Linux. I'm using the version `0.18.1`.

Does anyone encounter this problem?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz of the problem and also attach gifs to elaborate ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Will share this...

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Not yet. Still working on this...

Comment: Fixed the problem based on the Benny's answer. It was some styles we added on `.editor-container .view-line` (`font-family`, `font-size` and `letter-spacing`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem on Windows and it ended up being a font size issue! I can't quite remember, but something like it was calculating based off `font-size: x` but it was displaying `font-size: y`, but only in Windows. Double check you don't have a global font size on all divs or something, and that all your font names work on all OSes (e.g. make sure you're not only using Consolas or whatever). I had to do

```css
#monacodiv div, #monacoDiffEditor div {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: unset; 
}
```

to get it to work because in our environment we had a global

```css
body, td, div, p {
    font-family: Lato, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

setting that was throwing everything off.

Comment: This was the problem indeed. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

I was using a custom font and found that the behavior occurred because the Monaco editor was rendered on the screen before the font had time to load.
Once the font had loaded and was cached, the behavior no longer occurred.

I solved it by using the `document.fonts` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts) .

I added the following after Monaco editor had rendered:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
  monaco.editor.remeasureFonts()
})
```

This way if the font finished loading after Monaco editor rendered, fonts would get remeasured, making sure there was no offset in the editor content.